# How can I reduce the space between icons on wingpanel?

Tags: wingpanel

It is possible to remove this wasted space?

[image]

Comment: nope you cant, this is not in any config file is compiled from source, for that you must clone the source xode from github change de space, recompile and replace thte file in your system, thus when you computer updates it will erase your file and put the old one again

Comment: @RenatoA This should be an answer (and a good one) instead of a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will say "you can't" because it's very difficult and useless, what makes that space in Wingpanel isn't in any config file of the system, actually this kind of stuff is compiled from source code.

If you want to try the hard method,

- You will never be able to upgrade your system anymore (because it will erase your changes).
- You must know Vala very well and look for that line of code [here](https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel).

Then you must [compile the new source file](https://wiki.debian.org/BuildingTutorial), for finally [add it to your system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42968577/how-can-i-add-additional-source-files-when-customizing-and-rebuilding-debian-pac).

Good luck, I think is more easy to teach some UI lessons to the Elementary OS team. Or just hoping that they admit your line of code in Github.

Answer (score 7):

I was able to adjust mine.  Not sure if an update will affect it but now that i know where it is at i can reset it back to my liking should an update change it.

First, open files as an administrator.  Do this by right clicking files and selecting open as administrator.  Then you will have to select the root file system folder on the left hand side.  from there, here is the path to the file you will change.

```
usr/share/themes/elementary/gt-k3.0
```

The file you are going to change is named `apps.css`. I opened it with [code](/questions/tagged/code) by right clicking and selecting code from the "open with" selection.

**NOTE**: If there are lock symbols on the files and folders than you are not in as an administrator. You will not to be able to save your changes unless you are an administrator.

Once into the file, scroll most of the way down until you see:

```
composited-indicator {
    padding: 0 6px;
}

.composited-indicator > revealer label,
.composited-indicator > revealer image,
.composited-indicator > revealer spinner {
```

the line that says:

```
padding 0 6px;
```

Is the one that you will modify. Change the 6 to a 2. It should then look like:

```
composited-indicator {
    padding: 0 2px;
}

.composited-indicator > revealer label,
.composited-indicator > revealer image,
.composited-indicator > revealer spinner {
```

Once done exit and restart your system.

**Update**:  This answer is not my own, i had found this work around previously here on the site but haven't relocated it in order to provide a link and kudos back to the original poster.  if someone does find it please feel free to post link.

**Update 2.0**: link to original answer,
[How do I decrease the gap between icons in the status tray?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/17531/how-do-i-decrease-the-gap-between-icons-in-the-status-tray)

Comment: Only one clarification, the path is: /usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0

Answer (score 2):

This method taken from [this comment on Github](https://github.com/mdh34/elementary-indicators/issues/1#issuecomment-560757367) worked for me on 5.1 Hera:

1. Create a `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` file
2. Insert the below contents

```
/* source: https://github.com/mdh34/elementary-indicators/issues/1 */
.composited-indicator {
    padding: 0 2px;
}
```

3. Reboot your system

The other methods above didn't work for me in Hera, as `.composited-indicator` no longer exists within `/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0/apps.css`. This is probably a better method anyway, because `~/.config` user config, and so is less likely to be reverted when Wingpanel or the theme is updated in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a way to do this on 5.1 Hera? If I go to `/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0/`
and edit `apps.css`, there is no line containing

```
composited-indicator {
    padding: 0 6px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

marcussacana solution from https://github.com/mdh34/elementary-indicators/issues/1

Okay, I tried the community fork, and builded by myself, here is the [git](https://github.com/eth-p/wingpanel-indicator-ayatana), and if you don't want build:

1. Install the wingpanel indicator .deb [here](https://launchpad.net/%7Eelementary-os/+archive/ubuntu/stable/+files/wingpanel-indicator-ayatana_2.0.3+r27+pkg17%7Eubuntu0.4.1.1_amd64.deb) (the same deb in
   the link of this git)
2. Download
   [libayatana_compatibility.so.zip](https://github.com/mdh34/elementary-indicators/files/3776351/libayatana_compatibility.so.zip)
3. Go To (with sudo)
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wingpanel/

   cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wingpanel/
4. Backup your
   libayatana_compatibility.so

   sudo cp libayatana_compatibility.so libayatana_compatibility.so.copy
5. Replace the
   libayatana_compatibility.so with the zipped one

   cd ~
   cd Downloads
   sudo apt install unzip
   unzip libayatana_compatibility.so.zip
   sudo cp libayatana_compatibility.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wingpanel/
6. Reboot