# How do I decrease the gap between icons in the status tray?

Tags: wingpanel, release-juno

I followed this tutorial to show the tray icons again and it worked properly.

https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/16503/16719

However, there's a huge gap between the icons. How can I adjust it?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must edit `/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0/apps.css`, find this selector

```
.composited-indicator {
    padding: 0 6px; 
}
```

and change to

```
.composited-indicator {
    padding: 0 2px;
}
```

If you use another theme then change the path to `/usr/share/themes/MyTheme/gtk-3.0/apps.css`
You'll have to repeat it after every elementary theme update unless devs decide to change it.